# How to get the excerpts of all children pages

Tags: excerpt, children

I'm currently trying to get this working:

I want to display a list of excerpts of all children pages within my parent site. According to the WP Codex this ist possible through '[get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)' function and the key 'page_excerpt'. This is my approach:

```
    <?php $pagechildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) ); ?>
    <?php foreach ($pagechildren as $child) : ?>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <h2><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $child->page_excerpt; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Sadly, this is only working with the title. I don't get any result within the

tag for the exceprt. Whats wrong?

Comment: You need `post_excerpt`

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it should be `post_excerpt`.

Secondly, this just stores the manually added excerpt, so it returns empty if you don't have one.

Thirdly, you could [`setup_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata):

```
<?php $pagechildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $pagechildren as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        // code
<?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Do not forget to reset - [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

If you use `setup_postdata()`, then you can use e.g. [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)

```
setup_postdata( $post );
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
```

As [@birgire correctly noted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189930/how-to-get-the-excerpts-of-all-children-pages#comment276972_189931) usage of `$post` - instead of `$child` - is a must to use the template tags available reliably.

Comment: +1 but we must use `$post` instead of `$child` for `the_title()`, `get_the_title()`  and `the_ID()` to work within the loop here. It's possible though to use `get_the_title( $child )`. Just did some digging: the reason why `the_content()` works here is how `setup_postdata( $child )` extracts `$child->post_content` into the global `$pages` variable that's accessible to `$content` in `get_the_content()`.

Comment: The same thing has caused me trouble in the past. Just remembered it and thought it might save others some time and head scratching, by bringing it up in a comment ;-)

Comment: Constructive/productive criticism/additions is/are always welcome :) @birgire