# Random post, once per day

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I have a custom post type 'quotes' and I would like to display a random entry on the homepage each day.

This is the code I currently have to display the content:

```
            <?php query_posts( 'post_type=quote&orderby=rand&showposts=1' ); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-quote' );
                } else { ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/thumb1.jpg" alt="x" class="quote_person" />
                <?php } ?>
        <div class="quote_container">
            <span class="quote_intro hstack">Quote of the day:</span><a class="quote_tweet hstack" href="#">Tweet this quote <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <div class="quote_message white gstack"><?php the_field('quote'); ?></div>
            <div class="quote_source white hstack"><?php the_field('attribution'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Following the helpful suggestions I now have something that looks like the following:

```
            <?php 

        if ( false === ( $quotes = get_transient( 'random_quote' ) ) ) {
          // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

          $args = array(
             'post_type' => 'quote',
             'orderby'   => 'rand',
             'posts_per_page' => '1'
          );

          $quotes = get_posts( $args );

          //Now we store the array for one day.
          //Just change the last parameter for another timespan in seconds.
          $seconds_until_next_day = strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
          set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, $seconds_until_next_day );
        }

        foreach ( $quotes as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        if ( have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-quote' );
            } else { '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_directory') .'/img/thumb1.jpg" alt="University of Lincoln" class="quote_person" />'
            echo '<div class="quote_container">
                <span class="quote_intro hstack">Quote of the day:</span><a class="quote_tweet hstack" href="#">Tweet this quote <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <div class="quote_message white gstack" id="thequote">' . the_field('quote') . '</div>
                <div class="quote_source white hstack">' . the_field('attribution') . '</div>
            </div>
            '; }

        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();


        ?>
```

I'm not quite sure if I've got the foreach statement quite right.

Comment: Are we talking about each day as in calendar day or just changing in 24h intervals?

Comment: @kraftner Either would work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you really shouldn't be using `query_posts()`. [Read this excellent explanation why.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/47733)

Then this is a perfect use case for [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

You just get the post once and then cache it for 24 hours using the Transients API.

```
if ( false === ( $quotes = get_transient( 'random_quote' ) ) ) {
  // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

  $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'quote',
     'orderby'   => 'rand',
     'posts_per_page' => '1'
  );

  $quotes = get_posts( $args );

  //Now we store the array for one day.
  //Just change the last parameter for another timespan in seconds.
  set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
}
```

If your goal was to have it bound to calendar days and not 24 hours from last request replace the last line with the following. ([props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347934/3319382) to [chaos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47529/chaos))

```
$seconds_until_next_day = strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, $seconds_until_next_day );
```

After you have got the data you can just display it any way you want:

```
foreach ( $quotes as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

  [...]
  the_title();
  [...]

endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

[See this link for more examples.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Examples)

**EDIT:**

This should do the trick in your particular situation:

```
foreach ( $quotes as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-quote' );
    } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri (); ?>/img/thumb1.jpg" alt="x" class="quote_person" />
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="quote_container">
        <span class="quote_intro hstack">Quote of the day:</span><a class="quote_tweet hstack" href="#">Tweet this quote <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <div class="quote_message white gstack"><?php the_field('quote'); ?></div>
        <div class="quote_source white hstack"><?php the_field('attribution'); ?></div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: +1 and just a note about the foreach loop: I think it would be better to use `$post` instead of `$quote`, if you call `the_title()`. See for example this [comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189930/how-to-get-the-excerpts-of-all-children-pages/189931#comment276972_189931).

Comment: Updated as suggested by @birgire.

Comment: Exactly my line of thought. Really really good answer.

Comment: Thanks @kraftner - this looks like it's going to do what I need. I'm just unsure how to work the foreach statement correctly? I think I must be getting the syntax slightly wrong - I've edited my original question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: very clever;  and creative use of transients!